# Using :confirm in my link_to helper method in ruby on rails 4 has no effect what so ever. What could be wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

**This is my link_to method:**

```
<%= link_to 'Dispatch Now', order_path(order["objectId"]), :method => 'delete', :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

I've looked at my old ruby on rails 3 projects and this is how I've called confirm in my link_to helpers.

It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Has something changed with ruby on rails 4 that would have caused this to stop working? I have the jquery-rails file in my gemfile and I've checked my application.js file and everything looks fine.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

--

Rails 4 [changed the syntax](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), so that the `confirm` attribute is now handled in the `data` hash. Whereas before you could get away with `confirm:`, now you have to manage `data: { confirm: "your_confirmation" }`